# "Upcoming events" side box lists the wrong election end date

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

The side box that appears on every page currently displays that our moderator election ends in just under a day:

[image]

However, [the election page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/election) states that we have about 8 days left:

[image]

My guess is that this is because the end date of the nomination phase got pushed back a week. Can we update the side box to accurately capture the end date of the election?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for noticing.  I believe this was a problem only in the community announcement, because the election page still says it's over in eight days.  I have added seven days to the deadline in the announcement.